# c - designing thread-safe library

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm developing new library to port a bunch of my existing apps to universal piece of code and to share my experience with others (FOSS).

The library implementation itself doesn't use any global/static variables at all. Instead it provides opaque data types and corresponding accessor functions to perform different tasks on that data.

Future apps that will use this library may (and will) be multithreaded (e. g. GUI apps with realtime processing) so the question about thread safety arises. As for me there are two ways to implement it:

1. Upgrade current library code and implement some thread-aware stuff, for example, by using PThreads API. As for me it looks like this: for each and every potentially mutable object add some mutexes and respect them in accessor routines - setters, getters, reinitializers, etc.
2. Code client programs in such a way that no thread-specific problems (such as deadlocks, concurrency etc) will occur - by means of using the same PThreads in end-user apps, not the library.

From the first glance the first approach is more universal and flexible - end-user of my library should not be anxious about breaking things with multiple threads: library's internals will take care of accessing critical sections with the help of mutexes and other sync mechanisms. May be I lack some experience but I can't remember any projects where this approach was utilized. May be I haven't dig deep...

Second approach looks simpler (for me as library developer) because I'm offloading all thread-synchronization tasks to the end-user without own dealing with PThreads (or something similar).

My question is: is handling thread-safety issues purely in the library itself (approach 1) considered to be good practice? is offloading all thread-synchronization tasks to the end user leads to unnecessary overhead while using library while lightening its development?

EDIT: to conform SO style

Comment: Opinion and context based, VTC

Comment: First method forces users to include pthreads even if they don't need it.

Comment: this is a very broad topic, and while your question is valid in the grand scheme of things it is off-topic at SO.   Here are some opinionated thoughts: 

The easiest way would be to make sure everything is re-entrant; which means either you are maintaining separate structures on the stack frame OR you are using atomic guards for any heap write locks. You don't need to or worry about whether someone is using pthreads or something else. (unless your library is doing threading itself).

Comment: As an aside as an avid C programmer I would encourage you to look at Rust ;) this is HYPER opinionated but it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's a *right way*, but a good way is to provide the calling code with an opaque handle (like you are doing) and document that the handle you provided should only be used by one thread at a time.  Then it's up to the user to either make sure only one thread holds a copy of the handle (so that the other threads cannot access its resources, simply because they don't have access to the handle), or alternatively the calling code can share the handle across threads and explicitly serialize all its calls that use that handle via a mutex.

The advantage of doing it that way is that if the user wants to avoid the overhead of mutex-locking, he can; or if he wants to (carefully) share the handle amongst threads and serialize access to it, that's also an option.

You do of course need to make sure that your library code doesn't access any cross-thread-shared internal resources (or if it does, that it locks a shared mutex before doing so), but it sounds like you're probably already doing that.

Some examples of C libraries that use this approach:  The C runtime library (with its `FILE *` handles as returned by [fopen()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html), libsndfile (with its `SNDFILE *` handles as returned by [sf_open()](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/api.html#open)), OpenSSL (with its `SSL *` handles as returned by [SSL_new()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ssl_new))

Note that your option (1) adds overhead to every call, and probably won't be sufficient anyway, since if the user wants to call several methods atomically/together in sequence he will need to manually lock a mutex anyway.  As a counter-example, Java's original [java.util.Hashtable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) class implements this implicit-serialization-on-every-call approach and [has been deprecated](https://javasearch.buggybread.com/InterviewQuestions/questionSearch.php?searchOption=question&keyword=1577), largely because that approach to thread-safety was seen in retrospect as a misfeature.

Comment: Wow, it was a bit surprising for me. I've always thought that approach (1) is better, but now I can see your opinion. And yes, by using the opaque handles (actually, pointers to the allocated structs) I'm carrying all necessary state and data stuff in these structs so no library-global symbols exist.

Comment: Non-blocking algorithms can be broadly useful, and can be designed to support atomic transactions of almost arbitrary complexity.  Otherwise, a library which attempts to acquire and wait on locks will require users to consider many corner cases over which the library has no control,   In many situations, if user code is required to take care of locking itself, reasoning about all applicable corner cases will be easier than it would be if a library to manage other data structures also tried to include locking logic.

Answer (score 2):

The most broadly portable approach would be to require that client code supply definitions or callbacks to perform a few operations on the underlying platform in atomic fashion, with whatever memory barriers would be required, probably including a library that implements those methods using C11 atomic operations.  Atomic operations are better than locks because there's no need to worry about what an application should do if it can't complete an action immediately; allowing client code to supply the functions may be better than using C11 operations because many platforms will be able to handle a limited range of atomic operations directly on certain types without being able to handle all of the operations mandated by the C11 Standard.

Comment: Let's consider an example: I have GUI app, the UI stuff is being processed in thread (1) and data acquisition/processing is held in thread (2). During data processing some state variable of data object (e. g., signal strength) will be updated. I want my GUI thread (1) to pull new signal strength value from that data. To do so it should call some getter accessor, right? I can easily imagine how to do it with mutex (lock in (2) before processing, release in (2) upon exit, lock in (1) before accessing, release in (1) before exit) but barely can suggest a way with atomic operation

Comment: Also it is pretty clear how to do the same with callback - we're just calling user-specified callback upon reaching some point in our library's code. But as for me at least two problems are raising:
1. What if library and client app are written in different languages? For example, in my case library is in pure C while the most of clients will be C++/Qt-based.
2. What if we should do more than one action upon execution of library routine? In such case passing a bunch of callbacks doesn't seem to be a scalable way and mutex should perform better. May be I'm wrong...

Comment: @DrobotViktor: For your example, each client could have a three buffers with the state that should be displayed, and the UI could have two pointers that support atomic load/store with acquire/release semantics, one of which identifies the buffer that should be displayed next, and the other of which identifies the buffer if any that is presently being displayed.  To set the UI state, a client selects a buffer that isn't identified by either of those pointers, puts the new data there, and then writes the "next display value" pointer to the newly-filled buffer.

Comment: Use of callbacks will accommodate mixed-language programs far better than direct use of mutexes.  When using callbacks, a library in one language which creates or waits on a mutex could expose functions to create or wait on mutexes the same way, regardless of the language with which it was called.  Otherwise if a library written in Acme C creates a mutex using the Acme mutex functions, and a library in Bob's C Compiler tries to wait on it using BCC's mutex functions, hilarity would likely ensue.